# Как найти в БД содержимое переменной

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, phpmyadmin

Есть код запроса к бд на java

```
String req = "Select model FROM Product Where brand = " + brandListCB.getValue().toString();
```

Как добавить "brandListCB.getValue().toString();" для запроса в одинарные кавычки? Без них выбивает ошибку "Unknown column 'Atomic' in 'where clause'"

Comment: Формируя SQL-запрос указанным образом, вы получаете [_классическую SQL-инъекцию_](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) в своём коде.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Умная мысля приходит апосля.. Опубликовал вопрос и через минуту додумался до ответа, добавив одинарные кавычки в запрос.

```
String req = "Select model FROM Product Where brand = '" + brandListCB.getValue().toString() + "'";
```

Comment: Данное "решение" не рекомендуется, так как не защищено от SQL-инъекции. Используйте хотя бы `PreparedStatement` с параметром.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, сохраню информацию для дальнейшего изучения. На текущем этапе есть необходимость быстро написать программу для диплома, а времени нет(

Comment: Ну тогда надейтесь, что вам не слишком въедливый рецензент на диплом попадётся... :)